# Creating and extending a list in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
mylist=[]
mylist.append(7)
mylist.extend(range(9,12))
```

can such a thing be done in a single line **in python3**?

I feel it should be trivial, but for some reason I can't recall nor find how to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this one liner:

```
mylist = [7] + list(range(9,12))
```

It returns the desired list:

```
[7, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: I guess I'm missing something, since `for lid in [7] + range(9,len(row)):` gives me `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "range") to list`

Comment: This works in Python 2.7 -- maybe you are using another version? Check if the mylist=... assigment works for you.

Comment: `range` doesn't give a precalculated list anymore in Py3, but you can still explicitly make one out of it if you want that: `mylist = [7] + list(range(9, 12))`

Answer (score 2):

You can add whatever you want to the list constructor. For example:

```
mylist = [7]
```

Or:

```
mylist = list(range(9,12))
```

or, to chain the two together:

```
mylist = [7] + list(range(9,12))
```

For more complex constructions, list comprehensions are the way to go. For example:

```
mylist = [ (irow,icol) for irow in range(1,10) for irow in range(1,10) if i > j ]
```

More information on list comprehensions is available at:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

(**Edited** to reflect the change in the question).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 2.* as others have said

```
for lid in [7] + range(9,len(row)):
```

will work

if working with Python 3.*, as range now returns an iterator you need to explicitly convert to list

Option 1:

```
for lid in [7] + list(range(9,len(row))):
```

Option 2:

```
for lid in itertools.chain([7],range(9,len(row))):
```